# Combining a toolwindow with adornments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

## Preface

I am creating an extension that has to interact with editor viewports. For that I have created an extension with a toolwindow and a viewport adornment. The toolwindow contains some preferences which are specific to each open editor viewport.
When editor viewport changes focus, I want the toolwindow to show the preferences for the newly focused editor viewport and be able to edit the preferences for this viewport.

## Question

How do I communicate the focus-change from the adornments to the toolwindow? Additionally, how do I communicate my preferences from the toolwindow back to the adornments?

Comment: Do you mean set focus the control of toolwindow or show the toolwindow?

Comment: The problem I have is that my tool window and adornment instances seem to be completely isolated from each other, but I need to be able to pass data between the two. How do I do that?

Comment: you could create a static class with static property, the tool window set the value of property, and the adornment instances get the value of property.

Comment: There must be a better way than singletons

Comment: you can also use web service to retrieve related information. one window save information via web service,  and another window get the information from web service.